# Usar loop for para encontrar el máximo valor en una lista

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código que saque de delfstack:

```
numbers = [55, 4, 92, 1, 104, 64, 73, 99, 20]

max_value = None

for num in numbers:
    if (max_value is None or num > max_value):
        max_value = num

print('Maximum value:', max_value)
```

Y sirve para encontrar el máximo valor en una lista, sin embargo, no lo comprendo, por qué sirve siquiera siendo que max_value es None y no se puede comparar con int? Y aunque lo fuera, por qué es capaz de encontrar el máximo valor?

Comment: Sirve porque en el if hay **dos** condiciones. Una que es si `max_value` es `None` y otra que lo compara con un entero. En la primera iteración, la primera condición `max_value is None` será `true` por tanto, entrará dentro del `if` y asignará a la variable `max_value` el primer número en el bucle. A partir de ahí `max_value` ya es un entero por tanto la primera condición será siempre `false` y solo hará la comparación (`num > max_value`). Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Hola xBeiker, sí, te explicaste, de hecho lo entendí perfectamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cabe aclarar que en condiciones con or, si una condición da verdadero, no se evalua el resto. Por ejemplo en la condición `max_value is None or num > max_value`, si `max_value is None` da verdadero, `num > max_value` no se evalua. Algo similar pasa con and, pero cuando una condicion da False. Tiene que ver con [la tabla de verdad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_de_verdad). Por ejemplo, en el or, si uno de las comparaciones da verdadero, significa que todo es verdadero, por lo que no hace falta seguir haciendo comprobaciones.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es cómo inicializar `max_value`, pues cualquier valor numérico que uses puede ser mayor a los elementos de la lista.

Un patrón básico en Python es usar `None` para inicializar las variables cuando no tienes algo válido que asignarles.

Con eso, la instrucción

```
if (max_value is None or num > max_value):
        max_value = num
```

se lee así:

```
si este es el primer valor a examinar o
   si este valor es mayor que el maximo encontrando:
  entonces max_value = num
```

El resultado es que en la primera iteración le asignas el primer valor de la lista a `max_value`.

En las siguientes iteraciones, `max_value` será siempre distinto de `None` y lo único que valdra será comparar los valores.